# VB.NET ReportViewer: Merged columns when exporting to Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, reportviewer

I'm using a reportviewer in VB.NET.

When the user exports a report to Excel some of the columns get merged and hidden. is it possible to fix this?

Maybe by manipulating some code or a setting somewhere..?

Comment: What do you mean with 'merged and hidden'? Could it simply be that the columns are too small and overlapping each other (fixed by dragging them bigger)?

Comment: yes they are tiny, but in the design of reports there is never like an empty collumn so it has no reason to add one.
besides, the tiny collumns are merged with an other wider collumn with data in it, nd i see no pattern so dont know why or how..

Comment: Could you at least give some information on versions used: .NET, Excel, ASP? How are you using the ReportViewer - could you provide a piece of code that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Excel measures columns in pts, Report Viewer will let you measure in inches, pts, etc. If you are using in. in the report for your column widths try adjusting your column widths so that they convert without any rounding issues to pts. This worked for me. 
Conversion = 72 pts/inch. So 0.875 inch would convert to a nice even 63 points. Excel will be happy with that.
Here is a conversion calculator: http://dx.sheridan.com/advisor/converter.html

Comment: Or you could try expressing all your widths as pts, but I think this would be harder to work with.